# How to divide an int to receive a decimal?

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to calculate the area of a sector but when I divide `angleParse` by 360 and times it by `radiusParse`, I will sometimes receive a output of 0.

What happens and where do I need to fix it? (Sorry, if this is a weird question but I started learning C# yesterday, also I just started using StackOverflow today)

Frostbyte

```
static void AoaSc()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the radius of the circle in centimetres.");
    string radius = Console.ReadLine();
    int radiusParse;
    Int32.TryParse(radius, out radiusParse);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the angle of the sector.");
    string sectorAngle = Console.ReadLine();
    int angleParse;
    Int32.TryParse(sectorAngle, out angleParse);
    double area = radiusParse * angleParse / 360;
    Console.WriteLine("The area of the sector is: " + area + "cm²");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `360m` would be a `decimal` literal... (or 360.0 if you want a `double`?)

Comment: read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered integer division.  If `a` and `b` are `int`, then `a / b` is also an `int`, where the non-integer part has been truncated (i.e. everything following the decimal point has been cut off).

If you want the "true" result, one or more of the operands in your division needs to be a floating point.  Either of the following will work:

```
radiusParse * (double)angleParse / 360;
radiusParse * angleParse / 360.0;
```

Note that it's not sufficient to cast `radiusParse` to `double`, because the `/` operator has higher precedence than `*` (so the integer division happens first).

Finally, also note that [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) in .NET is its own type, and is distinct from `float` and `double`.

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you divide it by 360.0 it will work.

Alternatively declare a variable of type decimal and set this to 360.

```
private decimal degreesInCirle = 360;

// Other code removed...

double area = radiusParse * angleParse / degreesInCirle;
```